# How much gravity to make lead flow?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, material-science, fermi-problem

Lead is solid at room temperature.

But it is quite soft, so under strong enough gravity, it should be possible to pour it out of a container like sand. What gravity is that?

Let's do a Fermi estimate. I know little of material science, but this looks like a job for the shear modulus. A dimensional analysis tells me the shear modulus is equivalent to a pressure. Assuming a cube of lead 10 cm on one side, the pressure at the bottom is

$$
pressure = \frac{density \times length^3 \times gravity}{length^2}
$$

If deformation happens when $\text{pressure} > \text{shear modulus}$, we get

$$
gravity > \frac{shear\ modulus}{density \times length} = \frac{5.6 \times 10^9\ Pa}{11000\ kg.m^{-3}\times 0.1\ m} \simeq 5 \times 10^6 m.s^{-2}
$$

Which is about a million times the gravity on earth. That seems high. Did I get something wrong? If not, does anybody have a more precise estimate (or knows how to get one)?

Comment: Hi there! If you can deform a piece of lead by hand , then the force of gravity needed will not be that high as you calculated. If you put a piece of lead in a rotating cylinder it will deform when the centrifugal force equals that of your hands pulling lead. This doesn't mean that lead is liquified though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems highish, but not too crazy: max mountain heights scale as $1/g$, So under 5 million G a mountain would be a few cm.

But lead probably starts changing earlier: the yield limit and compressive strength is 4-12 MPa rather than in the GPa range. Plugging in that gives 3,600 to 11,000 m/s$^2$. Now we are in the few hundred to a thousand G range.

(Also, why shear modulus? Isn't Young's modulus the more obvious choice? Still, the yield limit is what really matters here.)

Comment: Indeed it seems it was the compression strength I was looking for, thanks!
1000x earth's gravity makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The [compressive strength](https://www.azom.com/properties.aspx?ArticleID=613) of lead is about 12 MPa (air pressure is about $10^5$ Pascal). If you know this you can calculate the strength of gravity needed to compress lead. It won't liquefy though.

That is if you put a piece of lead on top of another, in a strong enough gravity field, the piece of lead below will deform, thus so will both.

Comment: Yeah, I was careful to not use the words "liquefy" and "liquid" in my question for precisely this reason, but your other answer tricked me. =]
I think compression strength is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
What's the etiquette around here? Do you want to add the math to your answer? Should I edit my question? Post a new answer?

Answer (score 1):

This picture is complicated by the fact that at room temperature, lead will *creep* (stretch out like taffy) at very low applied stress levels. This means if you had a really big cube of lead on hand, it would creep under its own weight *without liquifying* and slowly sag into a squatty cylindrical shape. Note that creep is not accounted for in citations of lead's tensile or shear modulus or tensile or shear strength.

That said, I'll bet that if you rearrange your own equation you can solve for how high a pile of lead needs to be to fail in shear under one *g* in the absence of creep.

Comment: Very interesting! I think the creep effect is covered by using the compressive strength as suggested by Deschele's answer, right?

Comment: No it isn't: creep stress & strain are  *time dependent*, compressive strength is not.

Answer (score 0):

When gravity becomes high enough, every material will liquify. When the force of gravity on the particles constituting the material will become higher than the binding forces keeping the particles together the particles will be set free from their bond. The material will disintegrate (or liquify, though the liquid will be quite flat).

The problem, though, is that you have to find something to put your material on. Probably the thing where you put it on will liquify too. So you have to find something to put this something on...

Comment: Presumably there are levels of gravity where some stuff liquefies while some doesn't. I'm asking for the minimum level of gravity that will liquefy lead.

Comment: Why two answers to the same question?

Comment: @nasu Why not??

Comment: Well, if you think that your answer is wrong you can edit it and change it. I see that this is the usual procedure. Besides, for ths question, one of your answer says that it liquefy and the other that it does not. So which on it is? Or you are just hedging your bets? :)

Comment: @nasu Yes, indeed. If I think my answer was wrong then maybe I should fix it (though this would always be easy in hindsight). But I don't think my first answer is wrong. Lead (like all materials) will liquify in a very strong gravitational field. but this is not what the OP has in mind. Lead is soft and will first be flattened in a strong gravity field. I'm always hedging my bets... ;-)